# How to make a js code output run within a specific DIV background

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I run into a nice JS from codepen that outputs bouncing balls https://codepen.io/rglazebrook/pen/JbxaI
I tried to use it as a background to a specific div inside a webpage but when I use that code the output appears under the website footer (if you look into this empty page http://www.doronwolf.com/home2019/ and scroll way down you will see the bouncing are successfully loaded but only under the footer)
 so, how can I make that js code output run within the page and preferably within specific div called 'herosection' inside my page and not under the footer? down beleow, 
**you can see the js code but please note that it depends on an external script that can be found here: https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/sketch.js/master/js/sketch.min.js**

```
var particles = [],
particleCount = 200;
Particle = function(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = random(3,30);
  this.rgba = 'rgba('+floor(random(0,255))+','+floor(random(0,255))+','+floor(random(0,255))+','+random(.1,.8)+')';
  this.vx = random(-2,2);
  this.vy = random(-2,2);

  // Draw our particle to the canvas.
  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,TWO_PI);
    ctx.fill();
  };

  // Update our position.
  this.update = function(ctx) {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    // Bounce off edges.
    if(this.x + this.radius > ctx.width) {
      this.vx *= -1;
      this.x = ctx.width - this.radius;
    }
    if(this.x - this.radius < 0) {
      this.vx *= -1;
      this.x = this.radius;
    }
    if(this.y + this.radius > ctx.height) {
      this.vy *= -1;
      this.y = ctx.height - this.radius;
    }
    if(this.y - this.radius < 0) {
      this.vy *= -1;
      this.y = this.radius;
    }        
  }
};

var sketch = Sketch.create({
setup: function() {
var i = particleCount;
while(i--) {
  var p = new Particle(random(0, this.width),random(0, this.height));
  particles.push(p);
}
 },
update: function() {
var i = particleCount;
while(i--) { 
  particles[i].update(this);
}
},
draw: function() {
var i = particleCount;
while(i--) {
  particles[i].draw(this);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there isn't a simple way of doing this with only the sketchjs librarie. try wrapping it in the p5 framework, they have helpers for that.

I did basic positing using

`container: document.getElementById("YOURID")
 fullscreen: false,
 width: 3000,
 height: 400,`
 as options to the `Sketch.create()` function

[link to pen](https://codepen.io/chaoky/pen/rgQLjR)